# GetCommandLine() of other process?

Tags: c, winapi, process

Windows API has a [GetCommandLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that returns the command-line used to start the current process.

Is there an equivalent command to get the command-line of another process, using the handle returned by *OpenProcess()*?

Answer (score 0):

In the narrow scope of "checking that a PID file refers to the correct program", [GetProcessImageFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be a useful alternative.